# Populate labels in a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, label

I have 5 labels titled lblQuestion1, lblQuestion2, lblQuestion3... and as part of the loop below, when i=0, I want lblQuestion1.Text = reader["answer1"].ToString(); ...

i=1 --> lblQuestion2.Text = reader["answer1"].ToString(); ...

i=2 --> lblQuestion3.Text = reader["answer1"].ToString(); ......

However, this doesn't work so can someone suggest an alternative method.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn);

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                if (!(list.Contains(reader["question_id"].ToString())))
                {
                    list.Add(reader["question_id"].ToString());
                    //lblQuestion[i+1].Text = reader["answer1"].ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "(no questions found)";
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            lblError.Text = "Database connection error - failed to insert record.";
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: where you are setting label text??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I want to set it where I've wrote the comment //lblQuestion[i+1].Text = reader["answer1"].ToString();

Comment: what is lblQuestion[], where is it defined?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Nothing and nowhere. I'm trying to set the text of lblQuestion1, lblQuestion2, lblQuestion3, lblQuestion4, lblQuestion5 but I'm unsure how to.

Comment: you can do this way: ``lblQuestion1.Text = reader["answer1"].ToString();``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad As part of the loop, when i=0, I want lblQuestion1.Text = reader["answer1"].ToString(); ... when i=1 --> lblQuestion2.Text = reader["answer1"].ToString(); ... when i=2 --> lblQuestion3.Text = reader["answer1"].ToString(); ......

Comment: you have to put if condition:``if(i == 1){ lblQuestion1.Text = reader["answer1"].ToString();  } else if(i ==2){lblQuestion2.Text = reader["answer1"].ToString(); }``

Comment: You can't have a string reference your controls. You will have to use  FindControl to get the control instance

Comment: @MarkHall Can I use FindControl to get lblQuestion[i] as apposed to lblQuestion1? ... Once found, how would I modify the control eg. Control myControl1 = FindControl("lblQuestion1");  if (myControl1 != null) { }

Comment: @Bhav Check my answer, getting a little long winded for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your comment to my Comment. Since [`FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes a string as an input you would just create the string with the component name you are looking for. **Be aware that you have to use the FindControl Method of the container that your labels are in.**

From Link(*emphasis mine*):

> Use FindControl to access a control from a function in a code-behind page, to access a control that is inside another container, or in other circumstances where the target control is not directly accessible to the caller. **This method will find a control only if the control is directly contained by the specified container**; that is, the method does not search throughout a hierarchy of controls within controls. For information about how to find a control when you do not know its immediate container, see How to: Access Server Controls by ID.

so something like this should work for you.

```
 ((Label) this.FindControl("lblQuestion" + (i+1))).Text = reader["answer" + (i+1)].ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put references to the labels in an array and access them with that. I put five labels on a form (leaving their names as the defaults) and used this code as an example:

```
private void SetLabelsText()
{
    // Put references to the labels in an array
    Label[] labelsArray = { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5 };
    for (int i = 0; i < labelsArray.Count(); i++)
    {
        labelsArray[i].Text = "I am label " + (i + 1).ToString();
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetLabelsText();
}
```